# A bijective map from $\bf N \times N$ to $\bf N$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want a bijective map from $\bf N \times N$ to $\bf N$. I can think of injective map easily. But, bijective seems to be hard to think.

Comment: This has been asked here before. The diagonal argument is the usual way to do this, that is $(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(3,1),(2,2),(1,3),\ldots$

Comment: With over a thousand points at your disposal, I expect you to be able and use the search function of the site and show a little more effort in searching before posting questions.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/120393/construct-a-bijection-between-mathbbz-times-mathbbz-and-mathbbz and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54158/the-cartesian-product-mathbbn-times-mathbbn-is-countable and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16611/bijecting-a-countably-infinite-set-s-and-its-cartesian-product-s-times-s and there are probably a few more.

Comment: Take a look in my question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/427212/do-i-need-to-present-a-formula-in-this-proof I think it can help you out.

Comment: A more general question:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/278679/does-anyone-know-a-closed-form-expression-for-a-bijection-between-mathbbnk/395080#395080